# Obfuscate email address on php

Tags: php

I need to obfuscate or cover an email address on PHP.

For this, i have the next code.

```html
<td>
<p class="list-item-heading"><small><?= $row->email ?></small></p>
</td>
```

Where $row->email is

> realname_x123@gmail.com

.

I need to show this as

```
r*al****_x*2*@gmail.com
```

I need to replace with * ALWAYS the same parts of the string, not randomly because it will be shown on a list, maximun of 5 or 6 characters visible.

Anytips? I've tried with strpos, and str_replace with no success.

EDIT:
IF this cannot be do. It will be usefull also, for example, to only leave 3 chars from the beggining.

```
rea***********@gmail.com
```

I've found a workaround that suits for me.

```
<?php
                                function hideEmail($email)
                                {
                                $mail_segments = explode("@", $email);
                                    $mail_segments[0] = substr($mail_segments[0], 0, 1) . str_repeat("*", strlen($mail_segments[0]) - 2) . substr($mail_segments[0], -1);
                                $pos = strpos($mail_segments[1], '.');
                                    $mail_segments[1] = substr($mail_segments[1], 0, 1) . str_repeat("*", strlen($mail_segments[1]) - $pos+1) . substr($mail_segments[1], $pos-1);
                                return implode("@", $mail_segments);
                                }
                                ?>
```

Comment: Is that the users email? What if there is not the same number of characters? Then you can't mask the same characters

Comment: you want to replace * with the letters in the same position of every email? ex: `a*c*@gmail.com` and the same pattern for all the others? like `a*b*bbb@gmail.com`

Comment: Also show us those unsuccessful attempts with str_pos and str_replace

Comment: Exactly, the emails are real, and changing character length. I need a solution, where ALWAYS replace the same characters, and the mail can't be dumped or extracted, but it can be recognized. (Is for a referral system)

Comment: if you want to do it for a specific position you can do this by using an `array`

Comment: What should be the output of email `joe@....` or `al@....` or `a@....`? There are still unclear parts of the question before we can answer it. And we still want to see the code you had tried with.

Comment: Make an array of characters, replace the appropriate array elements, then join it back into a string.

Comment: Use `str_split()` to convert the string into an array.

Comment: ....this looks like a pretty good exercise to train some test-driven development: use some combinations of input data and expected obfuscated output in a data provider, call your magic method, and fiddle around until all test cases are green

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function mailObfuscate($mail) {
    //every second character replace with *
    $mail = explode('@',$mail);
    $array = str_split($mail[0]);
    
    $control = 0;
    $ret = '';
    foreach ($array as $char) {
        if ($control == 0) {$ret .= '*'; $control++;} else {$ret .= $char; $control=0;}
    }
    return $ret.'@'.$mail[1];
}
```

Comment: You Can easily rewrite it to Your needs.

Comment: You can use `$control = !$control;` https://3v4l.org/CHZNX but the question is not clear enough to really answer yet. OP needs to add what to do in other cases then the given example. And always let OP post his/her attempts before giving them the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :) Best regards.